# MSSQL and MYSQL Migration

Tags: mysql, sql-server, migration, database-migration

I have migration problem that must be resolved at ten days. I have middle sized c# web server that has 50.000 line of code and also I have middle sized SQL Server  that has triggers, storage procedures and 20 tables that contains at least 10 columns.

Because our Microsoft licences will be expired end of this month, we must convert project to project that uses mysql database for reducing our cost of server without buying Microsoft SQL Server licence. I cannot change adapter class simply because I did not wrote c# server code. If I want to make any changes on server program, I must understand whole project and I takes at least 2 weeks because of tons of codes.

What you advise me about migration process? I need quick and robust migration tactic. 
I cannot take backup because my server data exceeded 10TB data (yeah bad programming).

Thanks for advising.

Comment: Have you tried a MySQL client to this? Although it may not help you import the stored procedures, triggers, etc but with an ODBC driver it may make your job easy. I once used [SQLyog](https://www.webyog.com/product/sqlyog) for a similar import. You can try it too..:)

Answer (score 1):

Migration of stored code (procedures, triggers) would be challenging task. Please read this guide: https://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/white-papers/guide-to-migrating-from-sql-server-to-mysql/

I don't think that migration without changing c# code would be possible.